# Java, search for an element, if not found, add it

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am pretty new to streams.

I would like to stream the `geometries` `EC_Geometry` arraylist and if the `EC_Geometry` element is not present (or better `equals` never returns `true`), then I add it.

```
public void init(GL3 gl3, EC_Mesh mesh) {

    geometries.stream()
            .filter(geometry -> mesh.getGeometry().equals(geometry))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(..?);
}
```

But I am stuck at the last line

How can I solve it using streams?

Please note that `equals` is a method I wrote checking if the geometry is the same (i.e: if the triangles correspond)

Comment: what are you adding with this? `geometries::add`

Comment: It was an bad attempt of adding the `mesh.getGeometry()` to `geometries`

Comment: Note that your filter could be written as `mesh.getGeometry()::equals`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`orElse` will always run even if the value returned isn't used so it is preferable to use `orElseGet` here which will only run if nothing is found.

```
 geometries.stream()
            .filter(geometry -> mesh.getGeometry().equals(geometry))
            .findAny()
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                geometries.add(mesh.getGeometry());
                return mesh.getGeometry();
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems working. Ps: a semicolon is missing at the end of the `add` method, I can't modify just one character

Comment: `.filter(mesh.getGeometry()::equals)` avoids invoking `getGeometry()` for each stream element…

Comment: Can you elaborate, Holger?

Comment: @elect When calling `mesh.getGeometry()::equals`, you create an instance of a predicate which is referenced directly when calling a terminal operation, that way `mesh.getGeometry` is only called when creating the `Predicate`. If you instead pass a predicate with a lambda, the reference to the lambda is used as `Predicate`, hence at each iteration, you execute the complete chaining which result in an extra call to `mesh.getGeometry`.

Answer (score 3):

```
.findAny().orElse(..?);
```

is for Optional - if you would like to get first element found.

For what you would like to achieve the best approach would be just to:

```
meshG = mesh.getGeometry();
if (!geometries.contains(meshG)) {
   geometries.add(meshG);
}
```

No need to overuse Stream API.

Comment: I modified the question to make it clearer that I am not looking for java `Obejct` comparison

Comment: Oh well. At least I tried. Have fun with streams @elect :)

Comment: @elect: it doesn’t change the fact that this is the simplest, straight-forward solution and using a Stream instead is not an improvement.

Comment: Ok Holger, I'll think about, thanks for the feedback